# Confusion regarding spring boot Message Converters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm having an issue with downloading a pdf into a viewer.
The errors states that there is no converter

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.....controller.rest.DocumentController$$Lambda$894/964587173] with preset Content-Type 'application/pdf'
```

I'm using Spring boot and I assumed(and read that) these converters were enabled by default

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
```

When i check the actuator I only see the String and Jackson Message Converters..

I do have a WebMvcConfigurer that only overrides addViewControllers

Does anyone have any idea why the preset converters are not present?